# understanding the term "extension" ,"component" and "plugin" in xmpp?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

can anyone explain the different  "extension" ,"component" and "plugin" in xmpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *extension* to the **protocol**, a *component* for implementing part of the **protocol** and a *plugin* piece of software to an implementation of the **protocol**... at least that's my understanding the last time I put together a plugin to ejabberd.

Comment: does extension need extra plugin and install on server itself?  or client xmpp can use new extension without required install on server?

Comment: Depends on the server: with ejabberd, lots come by default. Of course, it depends what you are looking for.  The same goes for the client: if an extension to the protocol requires both the Client & Server to cooperate, then the Client too must have been crafted with the said extension to the protocol.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to add a few details to the accepted answer.

- **extension** : full name is XMPP Extension Proposal — *XEP* for short, new features built upon XMPP. XEPs are defined by the XMPP standard body, and available [here](http://xmpp.org/extensions/). They are documents.

This extension may then be implemented in two possible ways.

- **plugin**: written directly for the XMPP server, called *module* in `ejabberd` and *plugin* in `openfire`. They are not portable between XMPP implementations, and are usually written in the implementation language of the server (erlang or java)
- **component** : implements new features of the protocol, connected through the network to the server using the [Jabber Component Protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html). It means that it is portable between servers. Usually used for transports to other protocols, but some PubSub and MUC implementations are available as components.

The component protocol, [XEP-114](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html), is quite rough and limited and is said to be rewritten someday. It is actually a backspec, written from the original `jabberd` implementation.

Comment: Thank you, example is the best medicine for this one: "Usually used for transports to other protocols"